# fixed background doesn't work when I add video header (chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

You can see background effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/xorkme75/embedded/result/

background is `fixed` here. so when you scroll the page, you can see rest of the image. for example scroll down and you can see the lady's face.

Works both chrome and firefox.

But when I add video to header. This effect not working in chrome anymore. Here is example (please see in chrome): http://areafordemos.net63.net/chrome.html

**How did I break it?**

I added to CSS:

```
#video-container {  
    top: 10%;
    width:100%;
    height:70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:-1; 
    }

video.fillWidth {
    width:100%;
    }
```

and I added to HTML:

```
<div id="video-container">
    <video autoplay muted loop paused class="fillWidth">
        <source src="xhttp://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm"/>
        Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
</div><!-- end video-container -->
```

CSS Code of broken area:

```
.dzen_bg {
background-image: url('http://seventhqueen.com/themes/kleo/sensei-e-learning/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2015/06/hero16.jpg'); 
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: 100% 12px; 
background-attachment: fixed;
padding-top: 10px; 
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

When I delete `width: 100%;` from `video.fillWidth` for example effect is back but video doesn't look like I want. So I am literally stuck.

**What have I tried so far?**

I- I tried to add `z-index:-2;` to `.dzen_bg`. It actually solved it. But another problem occurred. After that, I can't hover the inside of that div `.dzen_bg` anymore. Doesn't respond to mouse moves.

II- I deleted  `height: 70%` in `#video-container`. Solves the problem as well but how I will set video height right now? It is covering the whole screen now. I also tried to  set `height: 70%` to `video.fillWidth` after but video doesn't cover the screen anymore.

I have never puzzled that much. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: for me its working as intended, I think; If I scroll down, in both examples the background image moves.

Comment: Which browser you are using? This problem only occurs on chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fiddle is fine, you just need to move your `section` down a bit.

I have made a working (with video) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xorkme75/2/) here is the [result](https://jsfiddle.net/xorkme75/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: the thing is it's work on https://jsfiddle.net but not in actual page.this is why i upload it to some free server. And, it needs to stay under video. That was my desire :(

Comment: well you don't need to move it down that much https://jsfiddle.net/xorkme75/3/embedded/result/

Comment: here is a live vsn of it (not free) http://rachelgallen.com/videotest.html I put a non-breaking space in the paragraph

Comment: i added a class to the paragraph above the video "vid" and gave it a margin-top of 30px. works now

Comment: I can't believe there is a solution! Tons of thanks @Rachel Gallen. tons of thanks!!